# Can a lower cabinet be used over a floor vent?

Tags: vent, ventilation, cabinets

I didn't see this question asked after my [search](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcabinets%5D%20vent) but I have a wall in the kitchen that has nothing against it and we are wanting to add some cabinets but towards the right of this wall, about 5' from it, is a vent in the floor. I was wondering if a lower base cabinet can be sectioned/front-cap removed or if there was a special fitting (such as a 90 vent cover just for the base of cabinets) to allow ventilation from a vent in the floor? We do get vary broad climate changes so I was curious to know if I do add a vent in the bottom base would that possibly warp the cabinet even if I insulate it?

Comment: What size is the duct? If it isn't too big it can be made into a toe space register in one cabinet. Other details to follow

Comment: It's a standard vent cover and I did find something like this [Plastic 90 deg. deflector](http://www.atlantasupply.com/swscripts/NLNETUPD.OBJ?REQR_TYPE=O&REQR_ID=NEW+CUSTOMER&ATH_ID=+&&LOC_NO=001&STOCK_NO=P50&REQUEST_ID=CSTKDET) but I'm afraid it would warp under the cabinet.

Comment: You don't use that under a cabinet, bad bad idea. What size is the duct under the register. It lifts out, you will see a metal liner

Comment: Ya I thought it was going to be a bad idea but when I removed it looked like a round 14" and when I was under there it appeared to be one of the last vents in the house since the unit is on the other end of the house next to the bedrooms.

Comment: The reason the size is needed, the opening cut into the toespace needs to be the same size, if not larger than the one in the floor. when elbows are added it restricts the flow a little and should be compensated for. If the duct is being made narrow, it also affects the flow and further compensation should be made

Comment: A 14" duct is huge but that don't mean too much especially at the end of a run. The install may have just preferred to run the trunk all the way to the register. Is the 14" round is what was coming up through the floor with a register on it? In other words it had a 14 or perhaps 16" diameter round finished cover over it so air would blow through....

Comment: It is probably good to have a picture, it would explain a lot...

Comment: In your fist comment you mention it is a standard size. There are many standard sizes, each one  made to work in different rooms or spaces with different requirements, the most common are 4X10, 4X12, 6X10 and 6X12. A 4X10 is a lot easier to transition into a toe space register than a 6X12

Comment: The builder of my (suburban subdivision) house did this in my master bathroom: there is a 6" hole in the floor below the cabinets, and there is a 6x2" hole with a metal vent cover over it in the toe kick. The furnace blasts air into the space below and most of it comes out the vent. This is on my to-do list of things to fix, because in the winter: 1) we can't adjust the flow of this vent and with the bathroom door closed it quickly gets to sauna-like temperatures, and: 2) it heats up the contents of that part of the cabinet enough that my wife can't store any makeup/mouthwash/soap/etc there.

Comment: Almost sounds like it would be better to make that section a desk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.

Relocating the vent, however, is a better general solution because:

- The HVAC system can operate closer to its design. Reduced size registers and additional bends change the back-pressure and can readily throw the system out of balance.
- Specialized registers and other parts are not required.
- The less common installation is more prone to errors than typical industry practices.

None of which is to say that this is or is not the right solution for any particular installation, but rather than it is really only the preferred solution for a set of edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to go to a specialized HVAC supplier (maybe grainger) but you need a shallow 90 degree going to rectangle kickout.  Basically you want the number of square inches from the incoming vent to equal what you will fan out using the toekick of your cabinets.

Not sure you would find exactly what you are looking for at big box.  The worst case scenario is that you buy a shallow 90 and bend duct to meet your needs.  I would really look into HVAC suppliers though and paying $30-50 for something custom might be worth it.  Think about the work and cost of relocating or doing something else.  And also the fact that the vent was probably put in that location for a reason.